# What to Split Duplicate or Repeated value in Variable?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to split a value which is coming from a variable.

E.g : Output Coming: 
Dim optext As String = RahulShukla<>Image<>Image<>Image<>Image<>Image<>

Desired OutPut:

RahulShukla<>Image<>

Comment: Show what you've tried and the output you're getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont want split, you want substring.

```
    Dim optext As String = "RahulShukla<>Image<>Image<>Image<>Image<>Image<>"
    optext = optext.Substring(0, optext.IndexOf("Image") + 7)
```

Comment: Please Remove Ban from my Question I am not able to Ask Question?? Pease someone help me